# Prevent Rollbacks - Spring Data, JUnit, & Neo4J

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have Spring Data Neo4j wired up and working nicely. I have set up a couple of unit tests, and am using the `@Transactional` annotation on the test class. The tests run, but the data they write is always rolled back. In the logs I can see:

```
] o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest ...
request: {"statements":[{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH ...
```

However I want to supress this, I've tried using (in Kotlin):

```
@Test
@Commit
fun myDbTest() {...}
```

and

```
@Test
@Rollback(false)
fun myDbTest() {...}
```

But the annotation is ignored?

I seem to have the opposite problem to most, where the rollback is wanted, but it doesn't work :) In my case the rollback works perfectly, and I wish to turn it off.

Comment: Just remove transactional from the test class and the data should be persistent.

Comment: I tried that too, but the unwind statements are still executed at the end of the test.

Comment: What version of SDN are you using? If it's before 4.2.x it may or may not honour the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-tx-enabling-transactions.  If you really need this behaviour it works on 4.2.x.  Alternatively you may wire up a `TransactionTemplate` instead of `@Transactional` which will allow you to have complete control of the transaction semantics (it's just more code).

Comment: @digx1 Spot on, cheers for that reference. I was using `4.1.4.RELEASE` but just moved to `4.2.0.M1`, and you are right, it does work now.

Comment: added my comment as an answer :D

Comment: @digx1 Happy to accept your answer. Actually I have wound back to `4.1.4.RELEASE` as I was surprised by the number of annotations that have been marked as depricated. I'll have another run at moving up to `~4.2.0` when I get a chance to scan the [migration guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/4.2.0.M1/reference/html/#migration) over the weekend. Cheers again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Integration Tests written against Spring Data Neo4j (SDN) between version `4.0.x` and `4.1.x` will not work according to the the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-tx-enabling-transactions).  This is because the Transaction Manager implementation was not integrated into the expected Spring Transaction ecosystem. As of `4.2.x` this has now been fixed and will work as per the documentation.

At the time of writing `4.2.0.M1` is the latest version but contains several critical bugs. `4.2.0.RC1` is due on November 28th 2016 and right now `4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` is actually quite stable (and has been for some time).

If you must use this behaviour with SDN prior to `4.2.x` yo may wire up a `TransactionTemplate` instead of `@Transactional` which will allow you to have complete control of the transaction semantics.